# Operator [] in two dimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector, operator-keyword

I want to create an operator [] in the case of two dimensional vector. After searching, I have found that it's impossible to pass two arguments. How I can obtain the value of `m_matrix[i][j]` in the main?

relevant code:

```
class MyMatrix  
{
    public:            // Methods

        MyMatrix();
        ~MyMatrix();

        int operator[] (int n);

    private:          // Attributes

        int m_n;
        int m_m;

        std:: vector <std:: vector <int> > m_matrix;

};

int MyMatrix::operator[](int n, int m)  // in the cpp
{
    if (n>=0 && m>=0 && n<=m_n && m<=m_m)
    {
      return m_matrix[n-1][m-1];
    }
    else
    {   cout<<"******************"<<endl;
        cout<<"No valid index"<<endl;
        cout<<"******************"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

...

mat_test1[2][2]; // for example in the main
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: `operator[]` can only take one argument, period. You can use `operator()`, or have `operator[]` return a proxy implementing itself `operator[]`.

Comment: You could use `operator()(size_t, size_t)` instead.

Comment: What about `std::vector<int>& operator[] (int n);`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Why?  What does that change, other than perpetrating the anti-pattern already present in the standard library.

Comment: @JamesKanze As far as I can see they need single element access from two indices. I can't see anything wrong with `m(a, b)`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I was criticizing the use of `size_t`, not `()`.  I mention this possibility in my own answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your responses!! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resume the comment, you may do:

```
class MyMatrix
{
public:

    // Other methods

    const std::vector<int>& operator[] (int m) const { return m_matrix.at(m); }
    std::vector<int>& operator[] (int m) { return m_matrix.at(m); }

    int operator () (int m, int n) const { return m_matrix.at(m).at(n); }
    int& operator () (int m, int n) { return m_matrix.at(m).at(n); }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_matrix;
};
```

**Note**: I used `at` instead of `[]` to use the check from vector and so it throws exception for out of bound access.

And then use it:

```
MyMatrix matrix(5, 4); // size of the matrix from constructor

matrix[0][1] = 42; // MyMatrix::operator [] followed by std::vector<int>::operator[]
matrix(2, 2) = 42; // MyMatrix::operator () (int, int);
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/ZMD4cg).

Comment: I'd be very surprised that `at` was appropriate.  Do you really think it reasonable for all clients to be able to recover from what is, probably, a programming error?

Comment: @JamesKanze: I think it is better than the OP's check. But `assert` would be even better.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the OP's check.  I agree, that's far worse.  An `assert` is what is required.

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried the code perhaps I didn't understand good  'std::vector<int>& MyMatrix::operator[] (int m)
 { return m_matrix[m]; }

 int& MyMatrix::operator () (int m, int n) { return m_matrix [m][n]; }' // in the cpp    and it didn't work what did I do wrong?

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for your response but if I want to obtain in the main the expression cout<<m[i][j]<<endl, I can't? When I try this, it doesn't work ...

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't really understand what you mean: I try to explain again I want to write a method for the operator [] such I can get the value of matrix[i][j] in the main. Sorry for my english

Comment: @Laura: Provided example uses `m[i][j]` in `main` successfully. Your try doesn't work but without more info from your side, I can only guess what's wrong.

Comment: Main: ׳cout<<"8) Operator Index - Return value according to index sent "<<endl; cout<<"test1 (2,2)"<<endl; cout<<mat_test1[2][2]<<endl; cout<<"test1 (2,3)"<<endl; //cout<<mat_test1[2][3])<<endl; cout<<"test2 (2,3)"<<endl; //cout<<mat_test2[2][3]<<endl; cout<<"test3 (2,2)"<<endl; //cout<<mat_test3[2][2]<<endl; ׳

Comment: @Jarod42 cpp: const std::vector<int>& MyMatrix::operator[] (int m) const { return m_matrix.at(m) }                                                                       int MyMatrix::operator () (int m, int n) const { return m_matrix.at(m).at(n);                h: onst std::vector<int>& operator[] (int m) const;                      int operator () (int m, int n) const

Comment: Can you provide link from online compiler with failing code ?

Comment: @Laura: Next time, do something minimal as state in [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like [failing code](http://ideone.com/um9HYe). My failing code has size `0 x 0` by default (with uninitialized variables). Your code doesn't compile due to typos, missing function (and the useless function should be removed from example)).

Comment: @Jarod42 what does it mean due to typos?

Comment: *small* error with quick writing : you declare `test1` and use `mat_test1`, missing `;`. but compiler out-spot all/most of them.

Comment: @Jarod42 I wrote only the relevant code I deleted a lot of lines it's the reason why. in my original code, there are not these errors but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: With a correct mcve, I can help, currently, I can only guess that your default constructor is buggy.

Comment: You can do a compilable example... But Ok, I see your issue. You have out of bound access, valid index for matrix *2x2* is [0][0], [0][1], [1][0] and [1][1].

Comment: @Jarod42 it works you're right ... thanks you for your patience

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, but in the end, they all come down to using a
proxy.

For various reasons, the usual implementation of a Matrix isn't
`std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, but simply `std::vector<T>`, with an
appropriate calculation of the index.   In this case:

```
class Matrix
{
    int myRows;
    int myColumns;
    std::vector<int> myData;

    class Proxy
    {
        Matrix* myOwner;
        int myRow;
    public:
        Proxy( Matrix* owner, int row )
            : myOwner( owner )
            , myRow( row )
        {
        }
        int& operator[]( int column )
        {
            return myOwner->get( myRow, column );
        }
    };
public:
    Matrix( int rows, int columns )
        : myRows( rows )
        , myColumns( columns )
        , myData( rows * columns )
    {
    }

    int& get( int row, int column )
    {
        assert( 0 <= row && row < myRows
                && 0 <= column && column < myColumns );
        return myData[ row * myColumns + column ];
    }

    Proxy operator[]( int row ) { return Proxy( this, row ); }
};
```

In fact, you'll want a few more overloads (and possibly two proxies) to
handle const and non-const overloads.  But this is the general pattern
for such things.

Be aware, too, that there are two conventions concerning such overloads.
One is to say that the `[]` returns a projection, and that the correct
solution for handling *indexing* into multi dimensional structures is to
overload `operator()` (which can be made to take an arbitrary number of
parameters).  I personally prefer the `[][]` solution, but this
preference is not universal; a lot of people with a more mathematical
background prefer using `()`.

Comment: Can you explain me what is a proxy please? (I'm a beginner beginner sorry )

Comment: @Laura A proxy is exactly what I showed; a class that stands in place of another, to offer an additional functionality.  The two most frequent uses (I think) are supporting multiple `[]`, as here, and simulating overloading on the return type.