# Using overloaded << operator with dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, operators

My problem as follows:

I want to read values from a file into a dynamic array of specific class called Voter, using an overloaded >> operator.
Then, i want to export my result to the screen to check my load with another overloaded << operator.

Using a normal array I get the result im after, but struggling with going dynamic.
I have read on the forums that vectors are maybe a better way to go, but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong on this one.

Thanks!

**Details:**

The file has 3 "values" seperated by a space:
id(string) nr(int) (1 or 0)bool

**Code extract:**

```
string RollFileName = "VotersRoll.dat";
ifstream inFile_VotersRoll;
inFile_VotersRoll.open(RollFileName);

if(inFile_VotersRoll.fail())
{
    printf("The VotersRoll.dat file failed to open.\n");
    exit(1);

}
//connect to in file



int numberOfEntries = 0;
Voter testVoter;
while(inFile_VotersRoll>>testVoter)
{
    numberOfEntries++;
}
//get number of voter objects from file

typedef Voter* VoterArrayPntr;
VoterArrayPntr rollArray;
rollArray = new Voter[numberOfEntries];
//create dynamic arrray for voter objects


while (inFile_VotersRoll>>*rollArray) {
    cout << *rollArray;

}
```

**Class (extract):**

```
class Voter
{
public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &inP, Voter &voterP);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &outP,const Voter &voterP);
private:
    string id;
    int nr_times_voted;
    bool voted;
}
```

**Friend functions:**

```
istream& operator>>(istream &inP,Voter &voterP)
{  
   inP >> voterP.id >> voterP.nr_times_voted >> voterP.voted;
   return inP; 
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &outP,const Voter &voterP)
{ 
   outP << voterP.id << voterP.nr_times_voted << voterP.voted;   
   return outP;
}
```

Comment: What are your input, output & error messages? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks philipxy - not really receiving any error messages:
I'm reading in this (the VotersRoll.dat file data):
19810102009 1 0
19792003008 2 0
19851010890 3 1
19900909897 2 0
19561812567 6 0
19682703345 7 1

With output currently just:
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: @Gpoo Please edit your question to put such additional information. As you can see it's not very well readable in a comment.

Comment: Do you "rewind" the file after you read it the first time?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  Thanks Joachim. No I do not. This looks to be the problem. Any guidance on how one would accomplish this? Just starting out with c++ so still learning the ins and outs.

Comment: Start with e.g. [this I/O class reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) and read about [seeking](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg).

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `std::vector` implements the concept of a dynamic array. This is not just "maybe" a better way. **Don't use `new[]` and `delete[]`!**

(In fact, `delete[]` is entirely missing from your example code. If you don't release the memory anywhere and the object is not conceptually meant to exist as long as the program runs, then that's a memory leak.)

As for why the code doesn't work here, let's first have a look at this loop:

```
int numberOfEntries = 0;
Voter testVoter;
while(inFile_VotersRoll>>testVoter)
{
    numberOfEntries++;
}
```

This is curious; your first read the *whole* file just to get the number of elements, and will then read it *again* to get the actual elements?

This is redundant. You should get everything in one loop.

But there are also two serious bugs here:

1. You have **arrived at the end of the file** before the second loop starts.
2. You use **only the first element** of your array.

Let's fix the first problem first. In the next loop,

```
typedef Voter* VoterArrayPntr;
VoterArrayPntr rollArray;
rollArray = new Voter[numberOfEntries];
//create dynamic arrray for voter objects

while (inFile_VotersRoll>>*rollArray) {
    cout << *rollArray;
}
```

the loop condition will never be true. Your `operator>>` is called once. The stream is returned from the operator. And finally, it is used in the loop condition, resulting in `false` – because you had already been at the end of the file.

A very quick fix would be to open a new stream for the same file to fix this:

```
typedef Voter* VoterArrayPntr;
VoterArrayPntr rollArray;
rollArray = new Voter[numberOfEntries];
//create dynamic arrray for voter objects

ifstream inFile_VotersRoll2; // ugly workaround
inFile_VotersRoll2.open(RollFileName);
while (inFile_VotersRoll2>>*rollArray) {
    cout << *rollArray;
}
```

This will read and print the whole file. But still, everything will have been read into and written from only the first element of the array. `*rollArray` refers to the first element, and `rollArray` never changes.

This second bug is fixed like this:

```
for (int index = 0; (index < numberOfEntries) && (inFile_VotersRoll2>>rollArray[index]); ++index) { 
    cout << rollArray[index];
}
```

But as I said before, your goal should be to read the whole thing at once. This implies increasing the array's size as you go. Fortunately, with `std::vector`, this is trivial, because `std::vector` does not only grow automatically, it also does so [in a clever way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232198/about-vectors-growth). And the memory is released automatically as well. Here we go, your complete example modified to use `std::vector`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stddef.h>

using namespace std; // just for quick'n'dirty test code

class Voter
{
public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &inP, Voter &voterP);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &outP,const Voter &voterP);
private:
    string id;
    int nr_times_voted;
    bool voted;
};

istream& operator>>(istream &inP,Voter &voterP)
{  
   inP >> voterP.id >> voterP.nr_times_voted >> voterP.voted;
   return inP; 
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &outP,const Voter &voterP)
{ 
   outP << voterP.id << voterP.nr_times_voted << voterP.voted;   
   return outP;
}

int main() {

    string RollFileName = "VotersRoll.dat";
    ifstream inFile_VotersRoll;
    inFile_VotersRoll.open(RollFileName);

    if(inFile_VotersRoll.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "The VotersRoll.dat file failed to open.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::vector<Voter> voters;

    Voter input;
    while (inFile_VotersRoll >> input) {
        voters.push_back(input);
    }

    for (auto const &voter : voters) {
        std::cout << voter << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. This has really helped me a lot. Still learning, so this type of post helps quite a lot!
Another question: in my source file I basically have a matrix (first column: string, second column: integer, third column: bool)
How would one read column 2 and 3 in using vectors as well?

Comment: @Gpoo: You would either have a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` or a `std::vector<T>` of size width*height, with additional logic to calculate the right offset. In both cases, you would wrap the vector in a `Matrix` class to encapsulate the additional complexity. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656251/operator-in-two-dimensional-vector

Answer (score 0):

> *"I want to understand what I'm doing wrong on this one."*

Your loop here

```
while (inFile_VotersRoll>>*rollArray) {
    cout << *rollArray;
}
```

will only write to the 1st element in the array. You need to increment the pointer to the next element after reading in:

```
inFile_VotersRoll.seekp(0); // Rewind to the beginning of inFile_VotersRoll

VoterArrayPntr curItem = rollArray;
while (inFile_VotersRoll>>*curItem) {
    cout << *curItem;
    curItem++; // <<<<<<
}
```

Comment: The problems with this is of course that the original pointer is lost.

Comment: Thanks πάντα ῥεῖ,  I tried it, but still not displaying anything. Maybe any other suggestions I can try out?

Comment: @Gpoo _" but still not displaying anything"_, well that must be a different problem.

Comment: @Gpoo You must reset the read pointer of `inFile_VotersRoll`, after you counted the number of entries: [`inFile_VotersRoll.seekp(0);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)